# Theres empty space between cursor and username in konsole Kubuntu 21.10

Tags: command-line, bash, kubuntu, kde, bashrc

This is a brand new installation of Kubuntu 21.10 and I cannot understand why there is space between the cursor and my PC's name when I open Konsole:

[image: Konsole]

I have tried researching for a solution and I found this article: [Konsole has whitespaces whenever I start](https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=227&t=153632). But I don't have a `.bashrc` file under my Home directory:

[image: Home directory]

If I open Dolphin as root, however, I have a `.bashrc` file under the root's Home directory:

[image: root's Home directory]

**UPDATE 1**

I have created the `.bashrc` file under my user's Home directory (`/home/krillavilla/.bashrc`) and pasted the code below into the file. This is the new change:

[image: Konsole still having the problem 1]

[image: Konsole still having the problem 2]

I have not modified the `.bashrc` file in these directories yet:

```
/root/.bashrc
/etc/bash.bashrc
```

**UPDATE 2**

When I install the Terminator terminal, it works fine:

[image: Terminator works fine]

Comment: Are you using themes, customizations?

Comment: @Nmath this is breeze.

Comment: If your user doesn't have a `~/.bashrc`, then `PS1` should fall back to the value defined in `/etc/bash.bashrc` I think

Answer (score 7):

I have found the solution. Apparently, changing the font in my System Settings from Noto to Roboto messed with it:

[image: System Settinga - Fonts]

When I changed it back to the default, everything came back to normal:

[image: Konsole looking normal]

Comment: It appears that your terminal isn't correctly calculating the width of your prompt when you use Roboto (which seems to be a variable-width font), so it's putting the cursor in the wrong place. When you switch back to the default (fixed-width) font, it gets the calculations correct, and the cursor is shown in the right place.

Answer (score 0):

Set this as your
`.bashrc`

```
# ~/.bashrc: executed by bash(1) for non-login shells.
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files (in the package bash-doc)
# for examples

# If not running interactively, don't do anything
case $- in
    *i*) ;;
      *) return;;
esac

# don't put duplicate lines or lines starting with space in the history.
# See bash(1) for more options
HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth

# append to the history file, don't overwrite it
shopt -s histappend

# for setting history length see HISTSIZE and HISTFILESIZE in bash(1)
HISTSIZE=1000
HISTFILESIZE=2000

# check the window size after each command and, if necessary,
# update the values of LINES and COLUMNS.
shopt -s checkwinsize

# If set, the pattern "**" used in a pathname expansion context will
# match all files and zero or more directories and subdirectories.
#shopt -s globstar

# make less more friendly for non-text input files, see lesspipe(1)
[ -x /usr/bin/lesspipe ] && eval "$(SHELL=/bin/sh lesspipe)"

# set variable identifying the chroot you work in (used in the prompt below)
if [ -z "${debian_chroot:-}" ] && [ -r /etc/debian_chroot ]; then
    debian_chroot=$(cat /etc/debian_chroot)
fi

# set a fancy prompt (non-color, unless we know we "want" color)
case "$TERM" in
    xterm-color|*-256color) color_prompt=yes;;
esac

# uncomment for a colored prompt, if the terminal has the capability; turned
# off by default to not distract the user: the focus in a terminal window
# should be on the output of commands, not on the prompt
#force_color_prompt=yes

if [ -n "$force_color_prompt" ]; then
    if [ -x /usr/bin/tput ] && tput setaf 1 >&/dev/null; then
        # We have color support; assume it's compliant with Ecma-48
        # (ISO/IEC-6429). (Lack of such support is extremely rare, and such
        # a case would tend to support setf rather than setaf.)
        color_prompt=yes
    else
        color_prompt=
    fi
fi

if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
else
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
fi
unset color_prompt force_color_prompt

# If this is an xterm set the title to user@host:dir
case "$TERM" in
xterm*|rxvt*)
    PS1="\[\e]0;${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h: \w\a\]$PS1"
    ;;
*)
    ;;
esac

# enable color support of ls and also add handy aliases
if [ -x /usr/bin/dircolors ]; then
    test -r ~/.dircolors && eval "$(dircolors -b ~/.dircolors)" || eval "$(dircolors -b)"
    alias ls='ls --color=auto'
    #alias dir='dir --color=auto'
    #alias vdir='vdir --color=auto'

    alias grep='grep --color=auto'
    alias fgrep='fgrep --color=auto'
    alias egrep='egrep --color=auto'
fi

# colored GCC warnings and errors
#export GCC_COLORS='error=01;31:warning=01;35:note=01;36:caret=01;32:locus=01:quote=01'

# some more ls aliases
alias ll='ls -alF'
alias la='ls -A'
alias l='ls -CF'

# Add an "alert" alias for long running commands.  Use like so:
#   sleep 10; alert
alias alert='notify-send --urgency=low -i "$([ $? = 0 ] && echo terminal || echo error)" "$(history|tail -n1|sed -e '\''s/^\s*[0-9]\+\s*//;s/[;&|]\s*alert$//'\'')"'

# Alias definitions.
# You may want to put all your additions into a separate file like
# ~/.bash_aliases, instead of adding them here directly.
# See /usr/share/doc/bash-doc/examples in the bash-doc package.

if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
    . ~/.bash_aliases
fi

# enable programmable completion features (you don't need to enable
# this, if it's already enabled in /etc/bash.bashrc and /etc/profile
# sources /etc/bash.bashrc).
if ! shopt -oq posix; then
  if [ -f /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion ]; then
    . /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion
  elif [ -f /etc/bash_completion ]; then
    . /etc/bash_completion
  fi
fi
```

also look at [this](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Spec/EnhancedBash)

note if this does not work which it may tell me what is changes